# How can I solve this KdV equation numerically by Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I have been trying to solve the following [Korteweg-de Vries (KdV) equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korteweg%E2%80%93de_Vries_equation) using **NDSolve** but nothing went right!

\begin{align}
    6 U_{t} + \frac{9}{2} U_{xxx} + 9 U U_{x} - 6 a U_{x} = 0\\
    U_{xx} + \frac{9}{2} U^2-6a =0
\end{align}

with initial condition:
\begin{align}
    U_{0}(x) = 2 a \sec^2\left(\sqrt{(3a/2)}x \right)
\end{align}

and the boundary conditions are:

$$
    U=U_{x}=U_{xx}=U_{xxx}=0
$$ as $x$ goes to $0$ and $a = 0.2$

Comment: Could you provide the actual Mathematic code you're using instead of the LaTeX format? Also in terms of LaTeX formatting you can use that directly here by putting it in `$$`

Comment: I just edited your formulas using „common sense“ (unfortuntely usually not helpful in Physics), please check. Also there is `\begin{align} … \\ … end{align}` for equations in MathJax. This [**tutorial on using MathJax**](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/200681) will leave no question unanswered regarding LaTex in this environment.

Comment: Thank you so much 
Sir.

Comment: I fail to undrestand..how you can have two equations and one unknown? Am I missing somthing?

Comment: These two equations refer to two separate questions, each main equations deeded to be solved along with the boundary and initial conditions, thanks